# Dynamically call a method on an instance of a class (User specifies instance name dynamically)

Tags: ruby, class, dynamic, methods, user-input

I have a class, named `Family Members` , (in the file `family_members.rb`) which contains attributes such as `name`, `sex`, `type`, `role`, and `age`.

I have created instances, called `fm1` , `fm2` `fm3` `fm4` and `fm5`.

```
#family_members.rb

require_relative 'family'
require_relative 'checkdetails'

class FamilyMembers < Family

  attr_accessor :name, :sex, :status, :age
  def initialize (name, sex, type, role, age)
    @name = name
    @sex = sex
    @type = type
    @role = role
    @age = age
  end

end

fm1 = FamilyMembers.new('Andrew','Male', 'Child', "Son" , "27" )
fm2 = FamilyMembers.new("Bill","Male", "Parent", "Father" , "63" )
fm3 = FamilyMembers.new("Samantha","Female", "Parent", "Mother" , "62" )
fm4 = FamilyMembers.new("Thomas","Male", "Child", "Dog" , "10" )
fm5 = FamilyMembers.new("Samantha", 'Female', "Child", "Dog" , "4" )
```

I have a method called `Parent?` that checks whether an instance of the class is a `Parent` or a `Child`, and it is called as shown below:

```
#check_details   //would like to use this method

fm4.parent?
```

Would it be possible for the user to dynamically select which instance of the class to check?

I created a method, called `check_details` in the `checkdetails.rb` file:

```
#checkdetails.rb

def check_details
  puts "What family to you want to check? choose 1 to 5"
  $family = 'fm' + gets.chomp
end
```

However, if I try to call the `parent` method like this:

```
check_details

$family.parent?
```

It gives me the following error:

```
`<top (required)>': undefined method `parent?' for "fm1":String (NoMethodError)
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Is there a way to do this dynamically? Possibly without a Global Variable - as this is considered to be bad practice?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can do what you try to do. check [`Kernel#eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) method. In this case your code will look like: `num = gets.chomp; eval("fm#{num}.parent?")` But it's better to use `Array` / `Hash` of `FamilyMembers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your FamilyMembers in an array or hash and then look them up by key.

```
fm = {}
fm[1] FamilyMembers.new('Andrew','Male', 'Child', "Son" , "27" )
fm[2] = FamilyMembers.new("Bill","Male", "Parent", "Father" , "63" )
fm[3] = FamilyMembers.new("Samantha","Female", "Parent", "Mother" , "62" )
fm[4] = FamilyMembers.new("Thomas","Male", "Child", "Dog" , "10" )
fm[5] = FamilyMembers.new("Samantha", 'Female', "Child", "Dog" , "4" )

answer = "3" # get this from the user.
num = answer.to_i

if fm.key?(num)
  fm[num].parent?
else 
  raise 'Invalid answer'
end
```

P.S. Ruby guidelines would suggest that "FamilyMembers" class should be called "FamilyMember".

Comment: Thanks, will try this shortly!

Comment: Thanks this works, I will accept your answer. However, I tried to put all the code inside a method called `check_details` in another file, but it will not let me call it, the error message is `undefined local variable or method 'check_details' for main:Object (NameError)`.. This is strange as I have been able to call other methods from this file. Have you any thoughts on this? Thanks

Comment: @Jenny  Nope.  It must not be getting loaded when needed.  Good luck!